# Cumulative summing vector components dictated by another vector in one run in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

Suppose I have two vectors of the same lenghth `v1=[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and `v2=[1,1,2,3,3,3]`, (a,b,c,d,e,f are some numbers). I want to create another vector, where the components of the first one are summed and ordered according to the second one. So the result above should be
`result=[a+b,c,d+e+f]`. I hope it is self-explanatory. Is it possible to do it in one step, not by a for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could multiply by a matrix that was constructed as `sparse` using `v2` as the row indices:

```
v1 * sparse( 1:numel( v2 ), v2, ones( size( v2 ) ) )
```

To gain insight into what this is doing you can examine the matrix itself:

```
M = sparse( 1:numel( v2 ), v2, ones( size( v2 ) ) )
full( M )
```

It displays as:

```
ans =

 1     0     0
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
```

Then remember that matrix multiplication works by mapping rows (the single row of `v1` in this case) onto each column and summing the products column-wise.

Comment: What would the complexity in the vector length be?

Comment: Space complexity is `O(n)` (provided you don't call `full(M)`, which I put there only for display purposes): a sparse matrix is just stored as 3 lists of length `n`: the row indices, the column indices, and the values themselves.  As for time complexity, I'm *fairly* sure that's also `O(n)` but wouldn't bet my life. The underlying binary implementation only carries out operations when it comes to a non-zero element, and there are only `n` of those, each one getting multiplied once and the result added once.  But test it for yourself.

Comment: see @Luis Mendo's answer below

Answer (score 2):

This is *exactly* what [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) does:

```
result = accumarray(v2(:), v1(:));
```

Comment: Knowledge. It ruins all the fun of problem-solving. +1

Comment: @jez :-) Here's some more knowledge: `result = sparse(1,v2,v1);`

Comment: So the sparse matrix constructor sums values when indices are repeated—that is indeed a fun fact. Interesting. And that certainly wins the "code golf" prize for the shortest solution (15 chars). But the OP's point about working on symbolic `v1` is interesting too: I bet only the multiplication solution works then (don't have symbolic toolbox, so can't test).

Comment: I agree, this is elegant. I did say that $a,b,c..$ are numbers but in reality they are symbolic variables and so jez's answer is the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrayfun` although it think it uses loops under the hood, but as it is compiled it will still be faster than writing the loops yourself:

```
 vec=unique(v2);
 result=arrayfun(@(x) sum(v1(v2==x)), vec);
```

Comment: I disagree... In _almost all_ cases I've seen, loops out perform arrayfun. But it's faster and easier to write...